# Show children inline in Django admin

Tags: python, django

In Django 1.11, I have 2 models, `Foo` and `Bar`:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Bar(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
```

When I visit the Foo page in the Django admin, I want to be able to see a list of its Bars underneath it. So I do this in `admin.py`:

```
class BarInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Bar

@admin.register(Foo)
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name')
    fields = ('name')
    inlines = [BarInline]
```

But what I really want is a list of clickable links to a separate page where I can edit each Bar (as well as a Add button to add a new Bar to this Foo). I.e. I don't want the entire inline form. How is this possible in Django?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
admin.py

from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.html import format_html_join

@admin.register(Foo)
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name')
    fields = ('name', get_related, )
    readonly_fields = (get_related, )

    def get_related(self, instance):
        obj = instance.bar_set.all()
        return format_html_join(
            ',',
            '<a href="{}">{}</a>',
            ((
                reverse('admin:{{ app_label }}_bar_change', args=(c.id,)), 
                c.name
            ) for c in obj),
        )
```

You can create a callable [readonly field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) which will return the reversed [admin url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls) of each relation wrapped in the relevant [html code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html_join).

This will result in something like:

> "your readonly field": link1, link2, link3

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Unfortunately this is not outputting any HTML.

Comment: @GluePear [Reverse relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects) are called with `<model_name>_set` unless you set a [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name). On error, this callable will fail silently, I think. Try: `>>> p = Foo.objects.first()` and then `>>>dir(p)` to see how you can call the related `Bar`. Otherwise, install [`ipdb`](https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb) and try to set `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()  # XXX BREAKPOINT` before `return` to get a debugging prompt.

Comment: @GluePear There is also a gotcha in the `admin:yourapp_bar_change`. `yourapp` is the name of the application your model `Bar` lies in. `yourproject/yourapp/models.py`. You can also find it in the admin url when you change an instance of the model `Bar`: Something like `http://127.0.0.1/admin/yourapp/bar/1/change/`. I changed `yourapp` to `{{ app_label }}` as in the docs.

Comment: Thanks for persevering. My problem was that I also needed to specify `get_related` in my `fields` variable (as well as in `readonly_fields`).

Comment: @GluePear Oh, indeed, I blindly copy-pasted the code, in my implementation I had `fileds='__all__'`.

Answer (score 2):

You can make all the fields readonly in `BarInline`.

```
class BarInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Bar
    readonly_fields = ('id', 'name', 'foo')
    extra = 0
```

And for the Add functionality you can modify the inline template or more easy probably, add a custom field in `FooAdmin`, something like:

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name')
    fields = ('name', 'custom_add_bar')
    inlines = [BarInline]

    def custom_add_bar(self, obj):
        add_url = reverse('admin:appname_bar_add')
        return mark_safe(f'<a href="{add_url}">Add Bar</a>')
```

[Documentation for reversing admin urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls)